# Dependence of roots on parameters

Tags: complex-analysis, several-complex-variables

Let a function $f$ be holomorphic in a polydisk $U=U'\times U_n$,and suppose that for each fixed $z'\in U'$ it has a unique zero $z_n = \alpha(z')$ in the disk $U_n$. Then the function $\alpha(z')$ is holomorphic in $U'$.
On the proof of this proposition,it says firstly by Rouché's theorem for the family of functions $f(z',z_n)$ depending on the parameter $z'\in U'$ implies that $\alpha(z')$ is continuous...
I'm totally puzzled why $\alpha(z')$ is continuous.Can you tell me?
Thank you in advance!
Now I'm not satisfied with the above proposition,I want to prove this:
Let a function $f$ be holomorphic in a polydisk $D=D'\times D_n$,and suppose that for each fixed $z'\in D'$ it has in $D_n\subset\mathbb{C}^n$ exactly $m$ geometrically distinct zeros with multiplicities $k_1,\ldots,k_m$ respectively.Then these zeros $\alpha_1(z'),\ldots,\alpha_m(z')$ depend holomorphiclly on $z'$.
How to use the above proposition or ideas in the proof of the last proposition to prove this problem?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

We don't need Rouché's theorem to see the continuity of $a(z')$.

The continuity - and even the holomorphy - of $a$ follows by the residue theorem, which yields the representation

$$a(z') = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\partial U_n} \zeta\frac{\frac{\partial f}{\partial z_n}(z',\zeta)}{f(z',\zeta)}\,d\zeta,\tag{1}$$

and standard results of integration theory (the Riemann integral suffices).

Since the integrand is continuous on $U'\times \partial U_n$, the continuity of $a$ is a classical result on parameter-dependent integrals.

Applying Morera's theorem for a coordinate of $z'$,

$$\begin{align}
\int_\gamma a(z'_1,\dotsc, z'_{k-1}, \eta, z'_{k+1},\dotsc,z'_{n-1})\,d\eta
&= \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\gamma \int_{\partial U_n} \zeta\frac{\frac{\partial f}{\partial z_n}(z'_1,\dotsc,\eta,\dotsc,z'_{n-1},\zeta)}{f(z'_1,\dotsc,\eta,\dotsc.z'_{n-1},\zeta)}\,d\zeta\,d\eta\\
&= \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\partial U_n}\int_\gamma  \zeta\frac{\frac{\partial f}{\partial z_n}(z'_1,\dotsc,\eta,\dotsc,z'_{n-1},\zeta)}{f(z'_1,\dotsc,\eta,\dotsc.z'_{n-1},\zeta)}\,d\eta\,d\zeta\\
&= \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\partial U_n}0\,d\zeta\\
&= 0,
\end{align}$$

where the change of the order of integration is justified by the continuity of the integrand on $\{(z'_1,\dotsc,z'_{k-1})\}\times\operatorname{Tr}\gamma \times \{(z'_{k+1},\dotsc,z'_{n-1})\}\times \partial U_n$ and compactness, shows that $a$ is separately holomorphic. A separately holomorphic continuous function is holomorphic, so the holomorphy of $a$ is established.

---

We can indeed use Rouché's theorem to see that $Z_f = \{z\in U : f(z) = 0\}$ has no limit points in $U'\times \partial U_n$, and the continuity of $a$, but that argument is less direct:

Fix $z'\in U'$. Since $U_n$ is open and $a(z') \in U_n$, $r := \inf \{\lvert z_n-a(z')\rvert : z_n \in \partial U_n\} > 0$. For every $0 < \varepsilon < r$, $f$ has no zero on $\{z'\}\times \{z_n : \lvert z_n-a(z')\rvert = \varepsilon\}$.

Let $\delta(\varepsilon) = \min \{\lvert f(z',z_n) : \lvert z_n-a(z')\rvert = \varepsilon\}$. By continuity of $f$, there is a neighbourhood $W_{\delta(\varepsilon)}$ of $z'$ with

$$\lvert f(w,z_n) - f(z',z_n)\rvert < \delta(\varepsilon)\tag{2}$$

for all $w\in W_{\delta(\varepsilon)}$ and all $z_n \in \partial U_n$. By Rouché's theorem, $(2)$ ensures that $\zeta \mapsto f(w,\zeta)$ has a unique zero in the disk $D_{\varepsilon}(a(z'))$ for every $w \in W_{\delta(\varepsilon)}$, and that means $\lvert a(w) - a(z')\rvert < \varepsilon$ for $w \in W_{\delta(\varepsilon)}$. That shows the continuity of $a$, and hence $a(z') \to \partial U_n \Longrightarrow z' \to \partial U'$, whence $Z_f$ has no limit points in $U'\times\partial U$.

To see the holomorphy of $a$, one can also differentiate under the integral sign in $(1)$, since $\lvert f(w,z_n)\rvert$ is bounded away from $0$ in a neighbourhood of $\{z'\}\times \partial U_n$, that is unproblematic.

Comment: I'm not satisfied by your answer:in order to show that $a(z')$ is holomorphic,I should interchange the integral and $\frac{\partial}{\partial\bar{z_n}}$,then the set $Z_f$ should not have limit points on $U'\times \partial U_n$,we should prove this clearly.However,thank you very much.

Comment: The continuity of $$\zeta\cdot \frac{\frac{\partial f}{\partial z_n}(z',\zeta)}{f(z',\zeta)}$$ on $U'\times \partial U_n$ yields the continuity of $a$ by classical results on parameter-dependent integrals. Then Morera's theorem shows that $a$ is separately holomorphic, hence holomorphic (If you have the big gun that a separately holomorphic function is holomorphic without continuity assumptions at your command, you can directly go to Morera). You don't need to show that $Z_f$ has no limit points in $U'\times \partial U_n$.

Comment: Nevertheless, I've added how to use Rouché's theorem, you may be interested in that.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm a stupid student.1.I have understand how to use Rouché's theorem to prove a is continuous,but I can't see why $Z_f = \{z\in U : f(z) = 0\}$ has no limit points in $U'\times \partial U_n$.  2.You are right that is unproblematic that we can differentiate under the integral sign in $(1)$ to see the holomorphy of a.I'm very appreciated.  3.I think applying Morera's theorem is unappropriate because $\zeta\frac{\frac{\partial f}{\partial z_n}(z',\zeta)}{f(z',\zeta)}$ may take the infinity.I'm afraid $\gamma$ go through the zero of $f(z',\zeta)$.Thank you very much for your patience.

Comment: Don't call yourself stupid without a good reason to do so. To see that the continuity together with $a(z')\in U_n$ implies that $Z_f$ has no limit point in $U'\times \partial U_n$, suppose $(w_0,z_0)$ were a limit point. But $w_0\in U'$, so $U_n \ni a(w_0)\neq z_0$, and there is a neighbourhood $D_{2\varepsilon}(a(w_0))$ contained in $U_n$. By continuity, there is a neighbourhood $W = B_\delta(w_0)$ of $w_0$ with $a(w) \in D_\varepsilon(a(w_0))$ for all $win W$, and hence $\lVert (z',a(z')) - (w_0,z_0)\rVert \geqslant \min \{\delta,\varepsilon\}$ for all $z'\in U'$, so $(w_0,z_0)$ is not a

Comment: limit point of $Z_f$, contrary to assumption. Re 3., there is no problem applying Morera's theorem, because $f$ has no zero on $U'\times \partial U_n$, and $\operatorname{Tr}\gamma \subset U'$, so the integrand has no poles (or points of indeterminacy) on $\operatorname{Tr}\gamma\times \partial U_n$ (ignoring the coordinates held fixed for simplicity of notation), it is a well-defined continuous $\mathbb{C}$-valued function.

Comment: Dear Daniel Fisher,after I was diagonosed as suffering from depression,I feel I become an idiot.But I really,really want to understand complex analytic sets.Actually I want to prove this:Let a function $f$ be holomorphic in a polydisk $D=D'\times D_n$,and suppose that for each fixed $z'\in D'$ it has in $D_n\subset\mathbb{C}^n$ exactly $m$ geometrically distinct zeros with multiplicities $k_1,\ldots,k_m$ respectively.Then these zeros $\alpha_1(z'),\ldots,\alpha_m(z')$ depend holomorphiclly on $z'$.

Comment: How to use the above proposition or ideas in the proof of the last proposition to prove this problem?Thank you very much,I feel shy for troubling you so many times.

Comment: No problem. (I'm about to go to bed, so after this, don't expect a reaction in the next hours;) If we consider the integrals $$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\partial U_n} \zeta^k\cdot\frac{\partial f/\partial z_n(z',\zeta)}{f(z',\zeta)}\,d\zeta$$ for $k = 1,2,\dotsc$, we get the sum of the powers of the zeros as holomorphic functions on $U'$. In the case of a single zero with multiplicity $1$, that directly gives the holomorphy with only $k=1$. For two zeros, $k=1$ and $k = 2$ and the formula for the zeros of a quadratic give the zeros as holomorphic functions. For the general case, there are no

Comment: explicit formulae for the zeros in terms of radicals, so I think one should rather look at it locally than globally. For each simple zero, you get the local holomorphy by the argument here, and since holomorphy is a local property, the global holomorphy. For multiple zeros, it is more complicated, in general, the zeros don't keep a constant multiple $> 1$, they branch. The holomorphy of each zero-function then needs to be argued by continuity and the removable singularity theorem.

Comment: Dear Daniel Fisher,I just read the proof on the Chirka's book 'complex analytic sets'.But I feel that argument is less direct.Thank you for your kind-heartedness and generousity to instruct me.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1.Similarly as in Proposition 1,$Z_f$has no limit points on $D'\times \partial D_n$.Let $\zeta'\in D'$,let $\alpha_1(\zeta'),\ldots,$$\alpha_m(\zeta')$be the zeros of $f(\zeta',z_n)$ in $D_n$,and let $U_{nj}:=\{|z_n-\alpha_j(\zeta')|\le r_{nj}\}$ are pairwise nonintersecting disks in $D_n$.Since $Z_f$ is closed in $D$,there exists a polydisk $U'\ni\zeta'$ such that $U'\times\partial U_{nj}\subset D\setminus Z_f$ for all $j=1,\ldots,m.$Since the number of distinct zeros of $f(Z',_n)$ in $D_n$ is $m$ by assumption,for fixed $z'\in U'$,in each $U_{nj}$,there is exactly one zero $\alpha_j(z')$ of $f(z',z_n)$ with multiplicity $k_j$.By Proposition 1 (in the polydisk $U'\times U_{nj}$),
$\alpha_j(z')$ is a holomorphic function in $U'$.
Step 2.This argument can be repeated in a neighborhood of any point $\zeta'\in D'$.By construction, the analytic elements obtained coincide, after a suitable renumbering,on the intersections of the corresponding polydisks in $D'$,and can therefore be analytically continued along any path in $D'$.Since $D'$ is simply connected, the monodromy Theorem that these elements make up the $m$ holomorphic functions $a_j(z')$.
Step 3.In each polydisk $U^j=U'\times U_{nj}$,we represent $f$ as $f(z)=(z_n-a_j(z'))^{k_j}\varphi_j(z)$ by Weierstrass preparation theorem,where $\varphi_j$ is holomorphic and zero free in $U^j$.Define $\varphi(z)=f(z)/\Pi_1^m(z_n-\alpha_j(z'))^{k_j}$.Then $\varphi$ is defined and holomorphic outside $Z_f$.In $U^j/Z_j,\varphi(z)=f(z)/\Pi_1^m(z_n-\alpha_j(z'))^{k_j}=\varphi_j(z)/\Pi_{i\ne j}(z_n-\alpha_i(z'))^{k_i}.$By the Riemann extension theorem,it can be defined holomorphically in all of $U_j$.Since the $U^j$ cover $Z_f \cap \{z'\in U'\}$,$\varphi$ is holomorphic and zero free in $U'\times D_n.$By covering $D'$ with such polydisk $U'$.We obtain that $\varphi$ is holomorphic and zero free in $D$.By the uniqueness of Weierstrass preparation theorem,we have $\alpha_1(\zeta'),\ldots,$$\alpha_m(\zeta')$ are holomorphic.